# Resolving HTML validation "Warning: trimming empty tag"

Tags: html, validation

```
Question: what about placing &nbsp; as the contents of the empty tag?
```

It validates, but is that considered a hack?

Comment: What code are you receiving this warning about?

Comment: Its a warning. I will not worry about it and probably will not provide an workaround for it. ( what do you use empty tags for anyways? Css placements? JS dom manipulation. May be reason you use it is a hack ;))

Comment: Good web development treats warnings as errors and errors as fatal. You should always strive for 100% compliant markup.

Comment: a few different areas, but most specifically, on a select with an empty option. ex: <option value=""></option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question and with the detail from your comment, it is not a hack, but it is most likely not best practice either.

If you are looking to have a blank item for default, I would recommend `--Select One--` instead, and if you are looking for a divider `--------` would probably be your best option.